# Extending whitespace in div to bottom of page

Tags: css, html

I'm working on my website that I need to be screenfilling in height.
It exists of header-banner-content within a container.

The container itself is within another div (shadowbox) who is a bit wider because there is a fade out/shadow-effect. Therefore shadowbox is 1150px width and container only 1024px.

Maybe it is a better way to suppress the inner div and work width a left and right padding but I find it better to work without the padding.

This is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bartimi/REpTA/

```
<div id="shadowbox">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            MENU
        </div>
        <div id="banner">
            BANNER
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="left">
                content left <br /><br />
            </div>        
            <div id="right">
                content right
            </div>
            <div id="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How can I make sure the #shadowbox-background goes to the bottom?**

CSS:

```
* {
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url('http://atrox.no-ip.org:8082/HIJW/images/bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#shadowbox {
    width: 1150px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://atrox.no-ip.org:8082/HIJW/images/shadowbox.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#container {
    width: 1024px;
}
#header {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: red;
}
#banner {
    top: 100px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 625px;
    background-color: green;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
#clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

to your code :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `min-height:100%` from `#shadowbox`and add this CSS :

```
html, body, #shadowbox {
    height:100%;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9upap/)

Comment: In FF the #shadowbox ends while the #container runs to the bottom of the page. How come?